# What is the best way to spend 8 hrs on Beijing Capital International Airport?

Tags: airports, china, beijing

I have an 8 hour layover in Beijing. (1 PM to 9 PM). What is the best way to spend the time at Beijing Capital International Airport?

Also, Please provide details such as where to keep the baggage and where to eat.

And regarding shopping, Is there something I shouldn't miss? Like something you would get for a cheaper rate there?

I don't mind spending upto say 500RMB.

Comment: Depending what passport you hold you may be able to leave the airport due to the [72-hour transit visa](http://en.bcia.com.cn/server/notice/72visafree/72visafree_policy.shtml) policy. Apart from that your question is quite broad, and eight hours is a long time ... I'm not sure it can be answered as stated without knowing more about what you like (to buy, eat), etc.

Comment: I'll prove to you why this is too broad a question: I would LOVE an 8 hour layover, I'd curl up in a chair and read a novel while watching people.... I'm betting that is not your cup of tea, however....

Comment: I am an Indian citizen having a single entry Chinese Business Visa (M).